# Is it possible to "browse" static resources from merged dictionaries?

Tags: wpf, xaml

When I define my own static resources and give them an x:Key property, it is always possible to have an auto-complete suggestion by that xaml-intellisense-thing. I just write `{StaticResource …` and here they are, all the x:Keys I defined for my resources.

Not the same if I merge resource dictionaries from a theme nuget package. The resources are there, they all have their keys, but the xaml-intellisense-thing doesn't suggest it when binding static resources. Which leads me to time consuming browsing through source files or demos to find the style I need.

Is it possible to change this behavior and have them in suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried this with vs2019 and the intellicode plug in? I haven't but I analyses your project doing it's AI stuff and could well change such behaviour.

Comment: I currently work in vs2019, but don't know about the plugin, will check.

Comment: @Andy so I've checked, I assume the intellicode is running by default in vs2019, but no, it doesn't suggest resource keys from external merged dictionaries.

Comment: You can see a star in front of the top intellisense suggestions when intellicode is running. These are the ones the ai decided you most likely want.